# For any smooth function $f$ on $[0,1]$, do we have $\lVert P_N f \lVert_{1} \leq \lVert f \rVert_1$ for $P_N$ defined by Fourier expansion?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $C^\infty[0,1]$ be the space of periodic smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with the period $1$. It is well-known to be a Frechet space with the uniform convergence of all derivatives.

Also, $\{ e^{2\pi inx} \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,1]$. Define $P_N : L^2[0,1] \to \langle e^{-2\pi i N x}, \cdots, e^{2\pi i Nx} \rangle$ be the projection operator onto the first $N^{th}$ Fourier modes.

Then, the domain of $P_N$ may be restricted to $C^\infty[0,1]$ and still retain continuity with respect to the Frechet topology.

Now, my question is that, given any $f \in C^\infty[0,1]$, do we have
\begin{equation}
\lVert P_N f \rVert_1 := \int_{[0,1]} \lvert P_N f (x) \rvert dx \leq \lVert  f \rVert_1
\end{equation}
for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ as well?

For the $L^2$ norm, it is quite obvious. However, I am not sure about the $L^1$ norm for smooth functions. I tried to apply Uniform Boundedness Principle for the Frechet spaces, but it only applies to the $L^\infty$ norms...so it seems quite nontrivial...Could anyone help me?

Comment: No. The operator norm of $P_N$ on $L^1$ is $\|D_N\|_1$ ($D_N$ = Dirichlet kernel), as we can see by testing on a sequence $f_n$ that is an  approximation to the identity and using Young's inequality for the other direction.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. The operator norm of $P_N$ is $O(\log n).$ See the book Fourier Analysis (Graduate Studies in Mathematics)
by Javier Duoandikoetxea, Page 8 Chapter 1.